# How can you show taxonomy child terms on the parent term page?

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to modify the default taxonomy view so it shows nodes tagged with that particular term (already done) plus all children of the taxonomy term you are viewing.

I have seen solutions for D7 but nothing for D8.

Comment: This worked without having to use a module: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251401/how-to-display-a-taxonomy-terms-immediate-children-on-its-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is with the use of https://www.drupal.org/project/eva which lets you attach any entity to any other entity

Just for demonstration I have setup

```
parent 1
  child 1.1
  child 1.2
parent 2
  child 2.1
  child 2.2
```

install and enable eva 
create a taxonomy terms view called `children` with no block or page display

[image: create taxonomy view]

Then add an `EVA` views display from the dropdown 
You will need to set a contextual filter `parent term` with following settings

```
Hide when value not available 
specify validation criteria 
   taxonomy term id: 
      [NAME-OF-VOCABULARY]
   hide view
```

[image: contextual filter settings]

and on entity content settings set `entity type: taxonomy term` and `bundle: [vocabulary name]`

[image: taxonomy term children view]

I had to clear cache so it does not hurt to do it and visit any of the taxonomy parent pages you should see the children terms

[image: parent and children terms]

you can change where the children are displayed at your taxonomy term display settings page

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. This should work I think. Hopefully there is no issues with the TVI module which I used to take over taxonomy term page.

Comment: you are welcome ... I don't think it will have any problem cooperating with TVI.

Comment: Just set up the view exactly like yours. My only question is what did you use for Taxonomy term: Parent term validation? Currently, I have When the filter value is not available - Provide default value - Type Taxonomy term ID from URL.  This is not working for me.

Comment: revised the answer please check

Comment: Perfect. It worked on a fresh Drupal install. Not working on my production site, but I will have to figure that out.

Comment: glad it worked out !!